# How can I split a string by two delimiters?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I know that you can split your string using `myString.split("something")`. But I do not know how I can split a string by two delimiters.

Example:

```
mySring = "abc==abc++abc==bc++abc";
```

I need something like this:

```
myString.split("==|++")
```

What is its regularExpression?

Comment: did you try that? what is the result?

Comment: you should have escaped `+`s with `\\+`s

Comment: @aniri It has exception.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use this :

```
 myString.split("(==)|(\\+\\+)")
```

Answer (score 11):

How I would do it if I had to split using two substrings:

```
String mainString = "This is a dummy string with both_spaces_and_underscores!"
String delimiter1 = " ";
String delimiter2 = "_";
mainString = mainString.replaceAll(delimiter2, delimiter1);
String[] split_string = mainString.split(delimiter1);
```

Replace all instances of second delimiter with first and split with first.

Note: using `replaceAll` allows you to use regexp for `delimiter2`. So, you should actually replace all matches of `delimiter2` with some string that matches `delimiter1`'s regexp.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this

```
        mySring = "abc==abc++abc==bc++abc";
        String[] splitString = myString.split("\\W+");
```

Regular expression **\W+** ---> it will split the string based upon non-word character.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
String str = "aa==bb++cc";
String[] split = str.split("={2}|\\+{2}");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

The answer is an array of

```
[aa, bb, cc]
```

The {2} matches two characters of the proceding character. That is either = or + (escaped)
The | matches either side

I am escaping the \ in java so the regex is actually `={2}|\+{2}`

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer but the regex has been just factorized by using {2} instead of manually re-writing the delimiters twice. I would say this is better added as a comment rather than extra answer